# How to mergeindex in solrnet

Tags: solr, solrnet

I can use solrnet to do crud to the index. Afaik, solrnet depend on init which specify schema of each connection. The question is, can I mergeindex using solrnet? is solrnet support it? I want to control my index from the application that makes solrnet have behavior like secondary index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SolrNet does not currently support the Multi-Core commands, please see [issue #8 on the SolrNet issues list](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=8&colspec=ID%20Type%20Priority%20Milestone%20Summary%20BlockedOn%20Stars).

According to the last entry in the issue, this support was started on a fork of the SolrNet source in GitHub. You might consider looking into what has already been started and perhaps completing the functionality and contributing it back to the project.